# Load data via GET from URL in Flash / AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I know it's 2016 and this is a question about Flash...

Sadly a lot of the Flash AS3 resources are no longer available as the format has fallen out of favour with web devs and the tutorials I have managed to find are all done on earlier versions of Flash - I have CS6, and some of the functions/commands don't seem to work the same way.

So my question for you S.O gurus...

How do I load any kind of data into a swf movie via a GET URL.

For example :

```
www.example.com/mymovie.swf?loadfile=myfile.mp3
```

I know I can do the following to load an external file :

```
var url:String = "http://example.com/myfile.mp3";
var soundFile:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);
```

But instead of hard coding the url how do I tell it to look for the data in the **loadfile** variable delivered via the incoming request?

Comment: Do you really call your .swf file on the server directly add you do in your code or do you have it embedded in an HTML page?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, swf is called directly on the server, no html involved, but I found the solution.. Just in case anybody else is looking for the same thing you have to use : loaderInfo.parameters['yourvar'] to get it from the url

Answer (score 2):

The answer in case anybody else stumbles across this :

```
loaderInfo.parameters['loadfile']
```

Gets the variable from the url